# Calculate no. of recurring customer per day per country and per 2 days

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create 3 new columns as following:

1. Unique customer count: Unique count of customer by customer ID grouped by Date and Country
2. Repeated from Previous Day: If a customer visits on a specific day after visiting the previous day, it should increment the count by 1.

For example, if customer ID 1001 from India visited on 2023-12-01 and 2023-12-02, on 2023-12-02, my repeated from previous day column should show 1 count. The unique customer count should also show as 1.

3. For Repeated from Previous 2 Days: If a customer visits on a specific day after visiting both the day before yesterday and yesterday, it should increment the count by 1. This is similar logic as previous one but customer must have visited 3 consecutive days to be counted as one. So if Customer ID 1001 visited on 2023-12-01, 2023-12-02 and 2023-12-03, in the dataframe it should show count as 1 under Repeated from Previous 2 days on 2023-12-03.

The result for the code I have is incorrect. Based on the sample data i have, China on 2023-12-02 should be having 0 count for Repeated from previous 2 days, since technically there's no data given for 2023-11-30. How do I update the code to account that?

Also, how can I further optimize this code to receive dynamic consecutive number of days input? Meaning, I should be able to specify if I want to see customer ID that visits consecutively for (desired input) number of days.

Note that if the customer visit multiple times in a day, it should only be counted as 1 in all columns.

The expected output for the given sample data should be per following:

| Date | Country | Unique Customer | Repeated from Previous Day | Repeated from Previous 2 Days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-12-01 | China | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-12-01 | South Korea | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-12-02 | China | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 2023-12-03 | China | 2 | 2 | 1 |

The code I have is per following:

```
import pandas as pd

# Expanded Example DataFrame
data = {
    'Date': ['2023-12-01', '2023-12-01', '2023-12-01', '2023-12-02','2023-12-03','2023-12-02','2023-12-03'],
    'Country': ['China', 'China','South Korea','China','China','China','China'],
    'Customer ID': [1001, 1001, 1002, 1001, 1001,1005,1005]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert 'Date' column to datetime format
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

# Sort by Date and Country for proper calculation
df = df.sort_values(['Country', 'Date'])

# Assign visit number within each day for each customer
df['Visit Number'] = df.groupby(['Date', 'Country', 'Customer ID']).cumcount() + 1

# Calculate unique customers for each day considering visit number
df['Unique customer'] = df.groupby(['Date', 'Country'])['Customer ID'].transform('nunique')

# Create a shifted column to identify previous day's data
df['Previous Date'] = df.groupby(['Country', 'Customer ID'])['Date'].shift()

# Identify customers present 2 days ago and yesterday
df['Repeated from Previous Day'] = df['Previous Date'].notnull() & (df['Date'] != df['Previous Date'])
df['Repeated from Previous Day'] = df.groupby(['Date', 'Country'])['Repeated from Previous Day'].transform('sum')

# Calculate "Repeated from Previous 2 Days" while considering the data's time frame
min_date = df['Date'].min()
df['Repeated from Previous 2 Days'] = (
    (df['Date'] - df['Previous Date']) <= pd.Timedelta(days=2)) & ~df['Previous Date'].isnull() & (df['Date'] != df['Previous Date'])
df.loc[df['Date'] == min_date, 'Repeated from Previous 2 Days'] = 0  # Adjust for the absence of data for the day preceding the earliest date
df['Repeated from Previous 2 Days'] = df.groupby(['Date', 'Country'])['Repeated from Previous 2 Days'].transform('sum').astype(int)

# Keep only the unique rows
result = df[['Date', 'Country', 'Unique customer', 'Repeated from Previous Day', 'Repeated from Previous 2 Days']].drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick:

```
# step 1: 'per customer' analysis of visits
df['visit'] = 1
df = df.pivot_table(index='Date', 
                    columns=['Country', 'Customer ID']).fillna(0).astype(int)['visit']

# step 2: take a rolling analysis of the visits (!) over the past n (say, 3) days - for all (!) customers
n = 3
df = df.rolling(n, min_periods=1).max().astype(int)

# step 3: stack the data back into your desired output format "Date x Country" 
df = df.stack('Country').fillna(0).astype(int)

# step 4: finally make the count of customers (not visits!) you have 
no_of_unique_visitors_per_day_per_country = df.sum(axis=1)
```

Your original question mixed up to two problem statements. You wanted to have a "per customer" analysis (who visited how often), but also aggregate it into a "per day per country" sum over customers. Let's break that ask up into 4 smaller steps:

1. First, it does a "per customer" analysis. That is: understand for each customer when he/she was there. Your current dataframe only contains the index (date, country, ID), but not the actual information (visit yes/no). Let's add the actual information column (visit = 1), then you can pivot, and voilà, start counting
2. Then, it analyses per customer whether a customer visited in the past rolling n days (say, n=3 meaning "today and 2 previous days") by taking the maximum (visited yes/no)
3. It brings the count of visits_in_past_n_days back to your aggregated data format (`Date` x `Country`)
4. Now that you know for each day and for each country whether each customer has visited, just take the row sum (it will count of all those that have visited)

Finally, this code is also "dynamic", because the number of days `n=3` is a parameter .. pack this into a function, and the output series will be your dyanmic analysis result.